# how can i call the method from the promise in vue 2?

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2, vue-component

```
 var cityPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      this.getAllCities();
      this.cities = this.cities.filter(data => {
        if (data.country_id === this.filCountry) {
          return data;
        }
      });
      resolve();

    });
```

I need to wait until the the response arrives from the ajax call and then perform the operation on received data?

Comment: Separately, it's not clear even if we look at the code in the picture what the question is.

Comment: i will update then.

Comment: The update addresses half the issue, see my (remaining) comment above. What ajax call? What operation? What data? `cities`? You seem to already have it. More: [help], [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If this Promise is created inside a Vue method, then you will need to use an arrow function, closure, or bind to define your callback in order to have access to the correct `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `then` once the promise has returned:

```
cityPromise.then(data => {
    // do something with data
})
```

Comment: i need to cal the getAllCities() method from the promise but this variable is not available in the promise its undefined.

Comment: I'm not following, this.getAllCities() does not belong to the promise. Is it defined in your component? Are you expecting to get the result of that call from the promise?